# Returning NULL if a value is not found in an array

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to check if a value exists in an array, **and if it does not, I'd like to return a NULL row for it, instead of no row.**

```
SELECT 
    users.id 
FROM 
    users 
WHERE 
    users.name = ANY('{ John, avocado, Carl }'::text[]);
```

Currently returns

```
id
1
2
```

I'd like it to return

```
id
1
NULL
2
```

Since `avocado` is not present in our `users` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id
FROM unnest('{John, avocado, Carl}'::text[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(name, num)
   LEFT JOIN users USING (name)
ORDER BY a.num;

 id 
----
  2

  1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: the only issue with this answer is that the `NULL` is automatically sent to the bottom (`1, 2, NULL`), how do I keep it in this order: `1, NULL, 2`

Comment: I have adapted the answer to this requirement.